# dynamics crm - how create an entity, then save the id in the same transaction

Tags: transactions, hyperlink, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have a .net program that must do this:

1. Create an entity: Account, Address, contact etc.
2. Retrieve the id of the newly created entity
3. Save this id as a new record in a custom entity, say "CreateJournal"
4. All these must happen in a kind of transaction. That is: steps 1 and 3 must go together: either fail or success

I tried this:

```
Account acc = new Account();
acc.Name = "test on " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
Context.AddObject(acc);

CreateJournal jEntry = new CreateJournal();
jEntry.targetid = acc.Id.ToString();
Context.AddObject(jEntry);

Context.SaveChanges();
```

But it doesn't work, the targetId is Guid.Empty.

Context is of type **OrganizationServiceContext**.

Answer (score 1):

Use plugin on each entity you are interested have a log, e.g. post stage plugin on create event, which will create your Journal entities. It will work in "transactional" mode.

Comment: That is a good idea, but then how can I know which "Contact" was created by my own code and which by the user? Because the plugin is executed for each of these 2 cases.

Comment: @Flavius There is no universal way to know "who" creates contact, but some workarounds are possible. e.g. add some new field which will be set only in your code, or, might be your code will work under some predefined users credentials.

Answer (score 1):

CRM supports assigning new objects their Ids before you create the record. Remember Guids, unlike integer Ids, are globally unique so it is common for guid-based systems to support this "set id first" behaviour.

Specific to your code... Try assigning acc.Id as follows:

```
Account acc = new Account();
acc.Name = "test on " + DateTime.Now.ToString();
acc.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
Context.AddObject(acc);
```

EDIT: (Sorry I didnt realize) this code is not running in plugin code, so you are out of luck for transactions. See http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en/crmdevelopment/thread/229dec17-6c49-43ad-9751-6ea61e4ecd36.

The transactional behaviour you may have heard of is partially documented here and explains the context of transaction support in CRM:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327941.aspx#bkmk_DatabaseTransactions

Comment: I tried this, but I don't understand why the "SaveChanges" doesn't behave like a transaction. What I did: I added a plugin for the "create" message of the CreateJournal entity (pre-operation) that throws an exception, so it will fail each time. Then I run the code, the account still appears and the CreateJournal doesn't.

Comment: are your plugin steps registered as asynchronous? They need to be synchronous to get the transactional behaviour you are looking for.

Comment: This code is not inside a plug-in, it's a console application. I initially thought that "Context.SaveChanges" acts like a transaction, but it doesn't. It indeeds sends the objects as a batch to the server, but once there, the insert-object is atomic.